# Contract Predecessor vs Signer vs Current

Tags: smartcontracts, nearprotocol

Can someone help me understand the relationship and distinction amongst these three concepts? It seems like `context.predecessor == context.contractName` checks are common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`signer` - account that signed the initial transaction.

`predecessor` -  the last account who made the current contract call.

`current` - the account of the contract.

For an example, consider contract `contract.near` and a user `alice.near`.

`alice.near` calls method `foo` on `contract.near`.  In the context of foo:

- `signer == alice.near`
- `predecessor == alice.near`
- `current == contract.near`

Then if a promise call is made to another method say `faa`, then its context is:

- `signer == alice.near`
- `predecessor == contract.near`
- `current == contract.near`

So the check `predecessor == current` or `context.predecessor == context.contractName` is to make sure that the contract was the account that made the contract call.  A method with this assertion is considered "private" because only the contract can call it even though it is part of a public facing API.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from sirwillem [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300205/12191085) explains it well

Just remember the idea behind assertions like `context.predecessor == context.contractName` can be:

- Calling private methods in a contract indirectly (which can only be called by the contract itself)
- Calling admin level methods that only the contract id (contract owner) should call